# Does Brawl work with Fist weapons?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

So in the Lunar New Year event I pulled [Xiao](http://exvius.gamepedia.com/Xiao) who has a trait called [Brawl](http://exvius.gamepedia.com/Brawl) which states the following,

> Boost ATK when unarmed

However I'd like to know if this works with [Fist weapons](http://exvius.gamepedia.com/Category:Fists) or not. As equipping and unequipping a weapon doesn't appear to directly adjust her stats.

So when it says unarmed, does it mean, no weapon equipped, or just fist weapons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a response I received on the discussion page of the exviuswiki.com stated that the character must have no weapons equipped at all to receive the bonus.

http://exvius.gamepedia.com/Talk:Brawl

Comment: I confirm, when equipping a Fist weapon, you loose the benefit of Brawl. This ability does worth nothing at all.